# How to enable Rust debugging when using WSL toolchain in CLion?

Tags: rust, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am new to Rust and I am using CLion and the Rust plugin from JetBrains on Windows now. It works well when I just compile and run. But when I start debugging, it shows a dialog like this even though I switch my toolchain to WSL.

[image: screenshot of WSL toolchain settings]

[image: screenshot of the error dialog]

I wonder whether WSL is a kind of GNU toolchain. And if it is, what should I do to enable Rust debugging?

Comment: Windows Subsystem Linux call the GNU toolchain and not MSVC.

Answer (score 5):

Rust provides two kinds of [Tier 1 toolchains](https://forge.rust-lang.org/platform-support.html#tier-1) for the Windows operating system: `pc-windows-msvc` and `pc-windows-gnu` (for `i686` and `x864_64` architectures, making 4 toolchains in total). Their differences are highlighted here: [What are the differences between the GNU and MSVC Rust toolchain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46931981/1233251)

WSL requires you to use the GNU toolchain. With Rustup, you can install it and make it the default (or configure it in your IDE of choice):

```
rustup toolchain add stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

Comment: `rustup default` implies `rustup toolchain add`, so the first line can be omitted.

Comment: @TimDiekmann That's because the latest Rustup automatically installs missing toolchains on some commands, including `rustup default` and `rustup override set`. Given that setting the default toolchain across the system might not always be desired, I chose to separate the two.

Comment: Thank you! I previously thought the toolchain is what about the CLion toolchain. I've mixed them up.