# How can I use CLion with the Windows Subsystem for Linux to develop a Linux Rust application?

Tags: windows, rust, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a project written in the Rust language in CLion that I want to be compiled in  the Windows Subsystem for Linux and then run there. I'm not sure at all that this is possible.

The poster of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723438/how-to-enable-rust-debugging-when-using-wsl-toolchain-in-clion) apparently has it working, but [this intellij-rust issue](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/1171) says it isn't possible. Someone in the comments [wrote a workaround](https://github.com/philippkeller/rustup-toolchain-proxy) that doesn't work for me.

How can I setup CLion to compile Rust code in the Windows Subsystem for Linux and run it there when I click on run in CLion?

I don't care about cross-compilation; I just want to be able to continue developing my application. In the end, I'll probably compile it in a clean Docker container on the machine where it will be executed.

Comment: There is value in being precise here. By "I don't care about cross-compilation" do you mean "I don't care where it's *compiled*, as long as it *runs* under WSL", or "I don't care where it *runs*, as long as it's *compiled* under WSL", or "I don't care if it runs anywhere else, as long as it *is compiled and runs* under WSL"? I'm guessing the last thing.

Comment: @trentcl The first one actually. "I don't care where it's compiled, as long as it runs under WSL" but with the extra qualifier that I want to be able to just click "Run" in CLion and it should compile "somewhere" and run in WSL. Since I also installed required C libraries in WSL it seems to me the best way would be the "compile and run in WSL" way.