# How to install Rust via CLI on Windows?

Tags: windows, rust, rustup

I am trying to install Rust via the command line on a Windows VM (https://github.com/sansyrox/robyn/pull/263). The script on the main Rust [installation website](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) only supports *nix os.

What are the commands to download and install Rust on a Windows VM?

Comment: There's a link that goes to the [the other installation page](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html) that has Windows-specific methods.

Comment: @wkl , all of them want you to use the gui installer. From what I can understand.

Comment: You can use Chocolatey, Scoop, and the page also links you to [rustup](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#other-ways-to-install-rustup). None of these require GUI installers.

Comment: @wkl , what will be the command to install everything from cli? Becase a simple curl or a wget doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Install it with [`scoop`](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Scoop) for easier package management on your system with a single command:

#### GNU toolchain

```
scoop install rustup-gnu
rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
```

or

#### `scoop install rustup` for MSVC toolchain

Then you can update `rustup` or uninstall it whenever you want with:

`scoop upgrade rustup`

`scoop uninstall rustup`.

Answer (score 0):

Follow directions in [Other ways to install `rustup`](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#other-ways-to-install-rustup). Download `rustup-init.exe` based on the target toolchain of your choice:

- 64-bit MSVC: [x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe](https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe)
- 64-bit GNU: [x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/rustup-init.exe](https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/rustup-init.exe)
- 32-bit MSVC: [i686-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe](https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/i686-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe)
- 32-bit GNU: [i686-pc-windows-gnu/rustup-init.exe](https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/i686-pc-windows-gnu/rustup-init.exe)

You can use `--help` to see what options there are to configure the installation:

```
> .\rustup-init.exe --help
rustup-init 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)
The installer for rustup

USAGE:
    rustup-init.exe [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

FLAGS:
    -v, --verbose                        Enable verbose output
    -q, --quiet                          Disable progress output
    -y                                   Disable confirmation prompt.
        --no-update-default-toolchain    Don't update any existing default toolchain after install
        --no-modify-path                 Don't configure the PATH environment variable
    -h, --help                           Prints help information
    -V, --version                        Prints version information

OPTIONS:
        --default-host <default-host>              Choose a default host triple
        --default-toolchain <default-toolchain>    Choose a default toolchain to install
        --profile <profile>                         [default: default]  [possible values: minimal, default, complete]
    -c, --component <components>...                Component name to also install
    -t, --target <targets>...                      Target name to also install
```

The basic `-y` should work for you; it will install `rustup` and the default toolchain. You can of course use `wget` to download the installer within a script.

```
> wget https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/rustup-init.exe
> .\rustup-init.exe -vy
```

Note, the MSVC toolchain will require you to install the Visual C++ Build Tools to function. I'm unsure how to install those in a CLI only environment. Hopefully the `.exe` for that functions similarly.

See also:

- [What are the differences between the GNU and MSVC Rust toolchain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46931981/2189130)
- [How to install Visual C++ Build tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40504552/2189130)