# error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm making wallpaper changer to image URL but the following error occurs when building.

```
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\self-contained\\crt2.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc7qIF1R\\symbols.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.11p7xw5v0twpm4hq.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.124j2uy169x2kwkp.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1dl0ah14f6suweh9.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1jiwok2fc7yp20mm.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1m7ggcznto0qa3rd.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1mgcszamy8ny9z8l.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1ng8f42s3acx7qjz.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1wlx1mqwvj54ajf9.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1wvhzr0djogjy99p.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1xw4oh37aulhea98.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.1z43s43wurqktxwv.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.281v59j5f7a7349r.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.2clwfypb31zc8k45.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.2frr5jgmdfjbfimw.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.2gujqxw8atgqi8ct.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.2idftkd6pa485tev.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.384zibojmwfb0z6z.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.38bsokmi60udq348.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.3mnpvit0omlllpos.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.3tlh9eat74kty3dg.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.3woar30wyriv097z.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.3wuh3tebtdn3ahdv.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.40lqpajxml7z3mi4.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.41xsxlanzb9fi5pb.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.42hco59i5pbj3l15.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.44l9mph4s0fzi2l6.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.4liwje0wu42byhmf.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.4lk1sa7c34pqbuvq.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.4lrn0fi26zs9022p.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.4ntxehqhtxfm94wz.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.52utyk0nmn33bfez.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.54i8xobc26sbuumr.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.594cqv4lyq82kkig.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.5b6zijf7f0fioiq.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.5cncihlfhcpy4wt5.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.9mgw7u9co4yqajf.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.asq9dquqoiuutn5.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.b6qanibm9svfea.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.cuw6dqrmxowlbfz.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.hxvbl4os0tj1p7w.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.l049s6qb595lvpd.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.lggu57av4qn596a.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.y8oic7xs3hfgy2j.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.10n2lju6k9nf6oc2.rcgu.o" "-L" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\windows_x86_64_gnu-0.36.1\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu-0.4.0\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libreqwest-9a4dbf57e5e68e7b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhyper_tls-8a0482fb4659a510.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinreg-a897339a4c6c55d0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libipnet-393332560769bdc3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtokio_native_tls-4bc660421a1455cf.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde_urlencoded-70b475bfabbb8d79.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libryu-22a0f0e0ed247dd7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libmime-4b5c2055228aafdd.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libencoding_rs-528d84842d22b0c8.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libserde-d4961a2614a0d31e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbase64-b7f87cdf4a51928b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libnative_tls-bd0691dd35222115.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libschannel-2646118c968cf43c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhyper-bebd1c6a1f1a7824.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwant-071d6aaa50ad8f23.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtry_lock-6da9e8de26d321e2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhttparse-13e2f5bb01dd3b49.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libh2-d55ab689902640c1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libindexmap-2bc4ea955b3e3aa0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhashbrown-e59b3db03d31a3c5.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtokio_util-bd921671f973341b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_sink-9fd382a6d1f8919d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtower_service-693aca6a299bb032.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtracing-e53e008555f938c3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtracing_core-d48e01ddf26f353a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_channel-22b37681ccc4048b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtokio-b50eed1a5182acf0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libnum_cpus-20a37198399e911a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsocket2-636e016b24023925.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libonce_cell-e038679e55576dc7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libmio-c55d1351ac10df6e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libparking_lot-b79a09e9dc50bd71.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libparking_lot_core-bbc3824816610d11.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwindows_sys-fab37101b795f52f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libsmallvec-ef1235668915d741.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblock_api-78941e9a03ad16be.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libscopeguard-2a7bbfe540a30236.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhttp_body-43848ee1906beb0c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblog-2d3f6a1ac0c1b8eb.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcfg_if-72a8b291ac67dff6.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_util-8233de5233dc4adb.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libmemchr-1365e87fbfb3bef2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_io-1fcac0135dadeda5.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libslab-93878fa209738e18.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpin_project_lite-544a20b554575466.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_task-d25349c000819aac.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpin_utils-14af90acd8154020.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfutures_core-867574b71b3a3776.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblazy_static-bf83e0f1c2c107f8.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\liburl-b87f39a295a688b2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libidna-8ccb3b1c3ce91c9c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_normalization-8b7a29d26200a785.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtinyvec-47ac7fb4f0f21a12.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libtinyvec_macros-37f2955dc576598a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libunicode_bidi-e9aaa15b7aeada98.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libform_urlencoded-236ebb7596fb2cd7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libpercent_encoding-0f5e76e6ce29b9b1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libhttp-e1ff65b4454f11bc.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libitoa-56ceb377788657c4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libbytes-bab31de51f324f85.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libfnv-05d66c9dc72c7a1d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwallpaper-2927b8d0f19d0384.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinreg-bb0669c93da55e63.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\libwinapi-8f58ddc95173dee0.rlib" "-Wl,--start-group" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-63790cb7e7741ec2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-abcb1ca87a57a92a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libobject-0fad8685c6bded4b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libmemchr-3299e57f1789d89d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libaddr2line-46e569780d4cdb16.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgimli-7f2b28079033f1f7.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_demangle-a8f70e26f876b556.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_detect-df1b92243550b9d9.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libhashbrown-a4978b2adb8ed9b0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-2ca1626763a5b906.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libadler-1f2ee56578e6e126.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-c63afc13f98349ad.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-f98069f5498f6844.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcfg_if-760411fe92f24889.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-de2a474a231ed78a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-b868ffdbcdd15814.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-ca51229fadfc456b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-bf3f327639d6dfed.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-d28d62d9ae273cdf.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lntdll" "-lwindows" "-lwinapi_advapi32" "-lwinapi_cfgmgr32" "-lwinapi_fwpuclnt" "-lwinapi_gdi32" "-lwinapi_kernel32" "-lwinapi_msimg32" "-lwinapi_ntdll" "-lwinapi_opengl32" "-lwinapi_user32" "-lwinapi_winspool" "-lwinapi_ws2_32" "-ladvapi32" "-luserenv" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32" "-lbcrypt" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-nostartfiles" "-L" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\self-contained" "-o" "C:\\Users\\firef\\IdeaProjects\\coolgirl\\target\\debug\\deps\\coolgirl-76f052e466ab9091.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "C:\\Users\\firef\\scoop\\persist\\rustup\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: ld: cannot find -lntdll
```

What should I do?

```ini
[dependencies]
wallpaper = "3.2.0"
reqwest = { version = "0.11.11", features = ["blocking"]}
tokio = { version = "1.21.0", features = ["full"] }
```

Comment: Do you really intend to use the toolchain `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`? Is MinGW well installed on your system?

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger I don't know what 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc' is. Develop/build with Intellij. Are there any other toolchains?

Comment: Yes, there are others. Refernces: https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/windows.html https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931981/what-are-the-differences-between-the-gnu-and-msvc-rust-toolchain). On windows, `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` usually gives the least hassle. We cannot further diagnose the problem with that toolchain unless more details about the machine are provided (i.e. how Rust was installed in the first place).